# Apply laravel validation rule to all fields at once

Tags: php, laravel

I have inputs, some of them are array inputs (e.g. `<input name="test[]">`) and some are normal ones.

Fields have some specific rules, but all of them share 2 rules together.

I want that same validation rule to be applied to all fields instead of copying the same thing again and again for like 10+ fields.

I tried:

```
$rules = [
    '*.*'     => ['max:100', new CustomRule], // Apply to all
    'name1'   => ['array'],
    'name1.*' => ['specific_rule'],
]
```

but it didn't work, then I moved that `*.*` to bottom like this:

```
$rules = [
    'name1'   => ['array'],
    'name1.*' => ['specific_rule'],
    '*.*'     => ['max:100', new CustomRule], // Apply to all
]
```

and then suddenly it works!

A little confused about why it doesn't work on top, and I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this.

Please advise.

## Edit:

The whole thing (removed some of the rules to simplify):

```
   $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

   $rules = [
        'contact'            => ['required', 'array'],
        'contact.name'       => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'contact.email'      => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email', 'max:255'],

        'subscription'        => ['required', 'array'],
        'subscription.type'   => ['nullable', 'integer'],

        '*.*' => [new CustomRule], // Works when it's here, doesn't work on top, this is a Regex rule, looking for some invalid characters in all inputs.
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return response()->json($validator->messages(), 400);
    }
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce this on a current project i have in tinker, both example should work

Comment: @mrhn No I just checked again, It does not apply the rule when it's on top (the validation is passed with invalid characters), but when it's on bottom, it throws an error. Laravel 6.14.0, I deliberately tried to pass invalid characters on both cases, no effect when it's on top.

Comment: how does your data you want to validate look like? how does name1 array looks?

Comment: @mrhn Edited the question.

Comment: I can confirm moving the rule to the bottom of the list does make a difference. It appears that the "wild card" rules are overwritten if you add specific rules underneath them. So, it will only apply to fields that are *not* listed below the line containing the wildcard. This does not appear to be documented... maybe it's a bug?